# Non static method getChildFragmentManager() cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: android, android-fragments

In fragment I am trying use getChildFragmentManager() in static method.  But it show error and suggest me make method not static.

```
Non static method getChildFragmentManager() cannot be referenced from a static context
```

fragment:

```
public class C_Fragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment

@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {



        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container, false);
    }

 static void updateProductList(){
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("kz.dreamwings.unimax.fragments.C_Category_A_prudacts")!=null) {
//                            C_Category_A_prudacts.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    Fragment frg = null;
                    frg = getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("kz.dreamwings.unimax.fragments.C_Category_A_prudacts");
                    final FragmentTransaction ft = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    ft.detach(frg);
                    ft.attach(frg);
                    ft.commit();
                }
            }
        }, 300);
    }
```

Comment: Then why are you making it static ?

Comment: @ShreeKrishna I want use it in other class

Comment: You can call the method from another class as long as you have an instance of `C_Fragment`.

Comment: You should not, Fairly the error says everything `,getChildFragmentManager` is a method of Fragment, Then how can you use that in static method ? That may be possibly called from another class even without an instance. So better not making it static.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you cannot access not-static context from static context. You're trying to get a fragment instance in your static method, you should do it outside the static method so you can access `getChildFragmentManager()`.

```
private static Fragment fragment;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    fragment = getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("kz.dreamwings.unimax.fragments.C_Category_A_prudacts");

    //.... other code
}

static void updateProductList(){
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (fragment!=null) {
                //.... other code
            }
            }
        }, 300);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method with creation of making object of specific class,without making the static method

For ex: 
If the class name is MainActivity.java

If the method name is updateProductList()
Just make an object of MainActivity like

```
MainActivity a = new MainActivity();
```

Then use this object to call method of MainActivity in other class

Like `a.updateProductList();`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call getFragmentManager() or getChildFragmentManager() from a static method in Java . Consider using an interface to or a callback to 
update your 'products list'

```
public interface OnDoneLoading{ 

   void updateProductsList();
   //or better use  void updateProductsList(ArrayList<Products> products);

}
```

implement this interface in your Fragment.